# Crear repositorio git y sincronizar con bitbucket

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Tengo creado un proyecto en bitbucket donde tengo la rama "master" pero me gustaría trabajar en la rama "develop" que no la tengo creada.

Ir haciendo haciendo allí las features y cuando tenga una versión estable pasarla a la rama de master.

Los pasos que he hecho al crear el proyecto han sido estos

Paso1 - Iniciar el proyecto git , dentro de mi proyecto con el comando "git  init"

Paso 2 - Commit inicial

Paso 3 - Decirle a mi git en local cual es el repositiro en remoto con el comando
git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.org/pepe1234/project_test.git

Y por último este comando "git push origin master"

Con esto quiero entender que todo los commits que haga a mi rama "develop" en local , al hacer
un push se debeb subir al repositorio de bitbucket , no????

Si ejecuto el comando "git remote -v" veo esto

C:\xampp\htdocs\test>git remote -v
origin  https://user@bitbucket.org/pepe1234/test.git (fetch)
origin  https://user@bitbucket.org/pepe1234/test.git (push)

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout -b develop # Si no existe te crea la rama develop
git push origin develop # Subes la rama develop
```

Edito
Completando la respuesta:

### Versión larga

Bitbucket no tiene una rama `deploy` lo que tienes es crearla tú ya que es una buena práctica más que otra cosa. Para crear una rama en `git` lo que hay que hacer es :

```
git branch deploy # Creamos la rama
```

El `checkout` de git se usa para cambiar de rama , pero con el `-b` lo que hace es *si no existe me lo creas*.

```
git branch deploy
git checkout deploy
```

O versión resumida

```
git checkout -b deploy
```

### Subida a git

Para subir un repositorio en `git` **dentro de la rama** es :

```
git push
```

Porque digo si estamos dentro porque si no subiremos la rama actual. Para evitar eso y no subir un master modificado (mala práctica). Usamos :

```
git push origin deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

`git push origin master` - Solo has pusheado la rama master, en el repositorio de bitbucket todavia no existe ninguna rama `develop`.

A la hora de trabajar con git todo lo que estes haciendo en local no se subira hasta que no hagas un push con la rama que quieres llegar a subir.

---

Si lo que buscas es subir tu rama `develop` debes espeficificar esta en vez de la `master`:

```
git push origin develop
```